How to use appsettings.json in program.cs without warning "ASP0000 Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an copy ..."
I am building a .net minimal api with a lot of settings defined via appsettings.json.
But how to use this setting classes in program.cs without the compiler generating the warning:

ASP0000   Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results
in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider
alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to
'Configure'.

What I do is:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); // Create a WebApplication builder
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.Configure<MYSettingFromAppsettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection(MYSettingFromAppsettings.Position));
builder.Services.AddSingleton(resolver =>
    resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MYSettingFromAppsettings>>().Value);

...//same for all the other settings

var corsConfig = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<MYSettingFromAppsettings>();

// use settings

To be clear, I do not only use the settings in program.cs I also us it via DI in the services (IOptions options)
So, what is best practice to work with type save setting classes in program.cs and also via DI?

The warning is correct. You want to do settings and setup in the StartAsync method of your components or services. I tried exactly what you are doing about a week ago, and the solution was to use Components correctly and within the normal Component life cycle.

The following:
var corsConfig = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<MYSettingFromAppsettings>();

Builds the service provider which should be avoided.
If you need to bind cofiguration before building container you can do something like:
var cfg = config.GetSection(MYSettingFromAppsettings.Position)
   .Get<MYSettingFromAppsettings>();

You can use the bound value (cfg) to register it in the DI container (though note that it will not reflect the configuration changes even if the provider supports it)
